# Atom or RSS, which one is better

Tags: xml, rss

I am planning to make an iPhone application that pulls the information from websites and lists it on the iPhone. The data is received either in Atom or RSS. I would love to know which one is better regarding these criteria:

```
Stability
Flexibility
Longevity
Expandability
```

The most important thing is that i would prefer to invest my work on a format that will be still used in the next 5 years. So which one seems to be better? Thanx in advance.

Comment: Hmm, RSS *is* XML. The question would make more sense if XML was replaced with Atom.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both formats are still popular and will be around in 5 years time, and you will find 100 of tools for generating and consuming both. But if your not bound by a legacy choise I would pick Atom because it's more flexible. Atom is spec'ed out better in RFC's and also has an official sister protocol (AtomPub) that is designed for updating resources.

Atom spec: http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc4287.txt

AtomPub spec: http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc5023.txt

So both formats are about equal in : Stability and Longevity
But Atom (with AtomPub) excels in: Flexibility and Expandability